# TargetPlatform.linux is not yet supported by the flutter_inappwebview plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

In my app, I am using `InAppWebView` to load a `SAML` URL to authenticate the user. The `InAppWebView` works fine in `Android` and `IOS`, but when I try to run the same App on the web, it gives me this error: `TargetPlatform. Linux is not yet supported by the flutter_inappwebview plugin.`.

**I know that the `InAppWebView` doesn't support the web, but I am posting this question hoping that someone will suggest alternate options to achieve this.**

This is how I am doing, which is working fine:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:feeta/services/TokenManager.dart';
import 'package:feeta/views/dashboard/MyDashboard.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class LoginWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginWebView({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginWebView> createState() => _LoginWebViewState();
}

class _LoginWebViewState extends State<LoginWebView> {
  final tokenManager = TokenManager();
  InAppWebViewController? inAppWebViewController;
  bool isShowingError = false;
  late var url;
  var initialUrl =
      "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/initsso?idpid=C02qtgmcd&spid=859837136968&forceauthn=false";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: InAppWebView(
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(initialUrl)),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                inAppWebViewController = controller;
              },
              onProgressChanged: onWebViewProgressChanged,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onWebViewProgressChanged(
      InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) async {
    if (progress == 100) {
      String html = await getHtmlFromWebViewController(controller);
      if (!isShowingError && html.contains('not_a_saml_app')) {
        isShowingError = true;
        // Show the error dialog and return
        showErrorDialog();
        return;
      }
      String token = extractTokenFromHTML(html);
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("My Token: $token");
      }
      if (token.isNotEmpty) {
        tokenManager.storeToken(token);
        navigateToNewScreen();
      }
    }
  }

  void showErrorDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      // Prevent dismissing the dialog by tapping outside
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("Login Error"),
          content: const Text(
              "Oops! It seems like you're trying to login with a personal or different email address. Please make sure to use your Lattice email ID for authentication."),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text("Retry"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                isShowingError = false;
                logout();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<String> getHtmlFromWebViewController(
      InAppWebViewController controller) async {
    try {
      String html = await controller.evaluateJavascript(
          source: 'document.documentElement.outerHTML;');
      return html;
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Error retrieving HTML: $e');
      }
      return '';
    }
  }

  String extractTokenFromHTML(String html) {
    try {
      // Extract the JSON string from the HTML
      String jsonString =
          html.substring(html.indexOf('{'), html.lastIndexOf('}') + 1);
      // Parse the JSON string
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
      // Extract the token from the JSON
      String _token = json['token'] as String;
      return _token;
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Error extracting token from HTML: $e');
      }
      return '';
    }
  }

  void logout() async {
    // Reload the initial login URL
    if (inAppWebViewController != null) {
      // // Clear WebView cache
      await inAppWebViewController!.clearCache();
      inAppWebViewController!.loadUrl(
        urlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(initialUrl)),
      );
    }
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("came back on this method");
    }
  }

  void navigateToNewScreen() async {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyDashboard()),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest an alternate option, on how I can run the app on the web?
I will be thankful!